# Swapping vectors

Tags: arrays, vector, rust, copy

I need to assign the values of one vector to another, like:

```
let mut vec_a: Vec<f64> = vec![0.1; 100];
let mut vec_b: Vec<f64> = vec![0.1; 100];

// Do something with vec_a. Real vectors are ~1e6 long    
unsafe {
    vec_b = Vec::from_raw_parts(&vec_a, vec_a.len(), vec_a.len());
}
```

I'm looking for help to answer these questions:

Is there a more efficient and safer way of doing this?

Why it has to be under `unsafe` code if everything is being handled by the same application/code?

If it is the correct way, will it have a difference if instead of `Vec::from_raw_parts` use `std::slice::from_raw_parts`?

The reason behind this need is to avoid copying the data. This may happen with a high frequency and every time, one vector will be the storage to keep track of a best solution (let's say `vec_a`), the other one will be exploring other solutions. When a better solution is found, the only thing that needs to be changed is the `pointer` to the vector, now `vec_a` stores the best solution that was found in `vec_b` and `vec_b` can keep exploring different solutions.

Comment: Why do you need to assing the values of one vector to another? Can't you work with slice references instead? Or maybe with references to vectors?

Comment: How is what you're asking different than `vec_b = vec_a.clone();`? You seem to be trying to avoid the copy, but if there's no copy, why have two vectors? (What you've written doesn't compile, so it's not quite clear what you expect the unsafe block to do.)

Comment: perhaps just `vec_b = vec_a;` ? or answering the title literally, theres `std::mem::swap(&mut vec_a, &mut vec_b)` ? neither of these copy the data

Comment: Note that your current code is _not_ safe as you will have two vectors pointing to the same data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The naive answer is fairly performant. A simple assignment (`best_solution = solution`) doesn't do a deep copy of the elements, it only transfers ownership and destroys the source.

```
let mut best_solution = vec![0.1; 100];
loop {
    let solution = generate_solution();
    if solution > best_solution {
        best_solution = solution;
    }
}
```

One thing you can do to make it more performant is to reduce allocations by using a persistent vec as scratch space (you may be getting at this in the code in your post). In that case you would use `std::mem::swap` to avoid destroying the scratch vec.

```
let mut best_solution = vec![0.1; 100];
let mut scratch_solution = vec![0.1; 100];
loop {
    generate_solution(&mut scratch_solution);
    if scratch_solution > best_solution {
        std::mem::swap(&mut best_solution, &mut scratch_solution);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use just swap and moves for this.
Check this test that shows that swapping vectors only change pointers:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v1 = vec![0; 100];
    let mut v2 = vec![0; 100];
    let old_ptr1 = v1.as_ptr();
    let old_ptr2 = v2.as_ptr();
    std::mem::swap(&mut v1, &mut v2);
    assert_eq!(old_ptr1, v2.as_ptr());
    assert_eq!(old_ptr2, v1.as_ptr());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell your intentions, but if you want to move all the values of source vector into a destination vector without loosing content of destination, then you can swap vectors contents without copying data. E.g.

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec_a: Vec<f64> = vec![0.1; 100];
    let mut vec_b: Vec<f64> = vec![0.2; 100];
    println!("{}", vec_a[0]); // 0.1
    println!("{}", vec_b[0]); // 0.2
    
    let (mut vec_a, mut vec_b) = (vec_b, vec_a);
    println!("{}", vec_a[0]); // 0.2
    println!("{}", vec_b[0]); // 0.1
}
```

Comment: This shadows the old variables `vec_a` and `vec_b` with new variables with the same name, just swapped. I can't think of any situation when this would be useful.